# AutodiscoverUrl throws an error but only when running on a network drive

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have a very strange issue. This code:

```
....
exchangeService [i].Credentials = new WebCredentials( "user", "pwd" );
exchangeService [i].AutodiscoverUrl( "the-user-email-address" );
```

Running it on C: hard drive it works fine and I can add new entries to the calendar.

Running it on a **any** network drive the `AutodiscoverUrl()` throws the error:

`The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))`

The content of the directories [HDD & Network] in which the program is located is equal!

*My question:*
What can be the reason this very simple program cannot be ran on a network drive?

**Update:**

It is running on Windows Server 2012 R2 and the network drive is a NFS drive which was connected via `mount ...`

Comment: I think i misunderstood then. Disregard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, dear Microsoft, this is a mystery:

It does not work on a NFS drive. When I try it on a samba network drive then it works. I don't believe even Microsoft could explain why it does not work on a NFS network drive.